# Trying to Create a Dynamic List of Values using While Loop in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, lov

So I am using Oracle APEX, and I am trying to create a dynamic list of values. So say I have a table called "Device" and two of the columns are "ID" and "Quantity."

I have a form where a user can choose a device, and from there I am trying to get the next form field to return a list of values of that devices quantity plus values subtracted by 1 until no longer greater than 0...so basically:

```
WHILE quantity > 0
LOOP
    quantity := quantity - 1;
```

So that say I choose the device iPad, and its quantity is 3, it will create a list of values (3, 2, 1). I currently have this LOV query working to get the quantity number itself:

```
select distinct quantity d, quantity r
from device
where device.id = :P2_DEVICEID
order by 1
```

So this just returns a LOV with just one value, the quantity of the device I chose 
(Note: P2_DEVICEID is the "Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)" so when someone chooses a device in the form from a dropdown LOV, it will refresh the quantity LOV based on what option someone chose for the device field)

But yeah, so I have tried this and variants of this but keep getting errors

```
WHILE quantity > 0
LOOP
select distinct quantity d, quantity r
from device
where device.id = :P2_DEVICEID
update quantity := quantity - 1;
END LOOP;
order by 1
```

This was the error for the above:

"Error during rendering of page item P2_DEVICEQUANTITY.
ORA-06550: line 6, column 24: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 9, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ORDER" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with

Comment: select and update are two seperate statements...your update statement needs to know what table it's updating and likely needs the deviceID where clause so it knows what row to update instead of all rows

Comment: This is a duplicate of the same question you asked earlier.  All you need to do is replace the quantity in the answer there (which was 4 in your example) with your query that returns the quantity by querying the `device` table.  If you don't understand how to do that, feel free to edit your earlier question to clarify where you're stuck.